# What do you call "people of centuries ago"?

Tags: word-choice

I heard *ancient people* doesn't always mean *our ancestors*, but I don't understand the difference between the two. Besides, I'm not sure *primitive people* and *remote ancestors* are much the same.

Comment: In what context? I might say "Centuries ago, people were blah..." This format allows you to specify an exact timeframe: "In the year 1346, people were blah..."

Comment: I'm with Laurel on this: it all depends on context. Depending on the situation you could say our predecessors or our forefathers?

Comment: Medievals? Dark Agers? Names are location-dependent. Ancient Greeks?

Comment: You could also say "In the olden days, people were..."

Comment: Note that *ancient **people*** are people who are very old; *ancient **peoples*** are groups of people who lived in ancient times. Either might or might not be your *ancestors*, depending on whether you descend from them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Richard Dawkins in *The Ancestor's Tale* in the section *The Tasmanian's Tale* (page 43 in my copy), computer modeling shows that 80% of people alive in Britain in 1000 CE are the ancestors of **all** modern British people; 20% of people in 1000 CE left **no** modern descendants.

The same should be true of Japan, or of any well defined population of roughly the same size.

Expanding from specific populations to the world as a whole, the point where everybody then alive is the ancestor of everybody now alive (or of nobody now alive), comes at about 3,500 years ago (footnote to page 45 on page 642 in my copy).

Thus, ancient people and ancestors mean pretty much the same thing, genetically, for (almost) everyone in the world, if we are referring to people living about or before 1500 BCE.

But, does this answer your English question?

**First, *primitive peoples* and *remote ancestors* cannot be used interchangeably.**  For example, a modern citizen of Greece would regard a citizen of Athens in 500 BCE as a remote ancestor, but no one would call the classical Greeks a primitive people. I am sure that the OP can say the same about a long-ago period of high culture in Japan.

**Can we use *ancient people* and *ancestors* interchangeably?**  Considering the evidence we have from genetics, we can, as long as we really mean ancient.  According to [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/ancient), **ancient** refers to:

> Of, relating to, or belonging to times long past, especially before
>   the fall of the Western Roman Empire (ad 476)

Japanese and other cultures prbably have similar definitions of ancient.  The point is, ancient doesn't mean a couple of hundred years ago; it means, at a minimum, well over a thousand year ago.

If you are are referring to a time when not everyone was an ancestor of the population you are talking about, I like the suggestion of @Matt:

> forefathers (or foremothers):  A person who is from an earlier time
>   and has originated or contributed to a common tradition shared by a
>   particular group.

Definition from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/)

Or, as @Laurel said, say something like:

> "People in the Nth century in Country C ......."